# Is there any way for network tracing for Windows Phone 8 emulator?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm using WebClient to send a `GET` request to a PHP file (which writes the parameter values in the request to a file). I want to test whether my emulator actually sends such requests. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can trace network traffic for you.

It can be a little tricky to set up however. See http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/phone.asp for more details of how to set it up.